# Error with TextMate 2, PATH, --shell-escape and gnuplot in 10.8.2

Tags: gnuplot, paths, textmate

I reopen this post, which was started some time ago but didn't came with a solution. I don't really remember what was the exact problem with this (well, of course, `gnuplot` didn't work correctly). So I write here my actual problem, which is the same as before.

### Problem

I reinstalled the operating system (Mac OS X 10.8.2), installed MacTeX (the last one), installed MacPorts and `gnuplot` through it (in an administrator account). In this account, the command `port` works correctly from terminal (which let mi install `gnuplot`), and also does `gnuplot` app (from terminal). Then created a new (non-admin) account, and then neither `port` nor `gnuplot` worked. After little hacking ([here it is more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15047381/problems-with-macports-and-gnuplot-different-users/15047499#comment21152621_15047499)), I solved it.
Now `port` and `gnuplot` work both from terminal in both accounts.

But here is the problem. I use TextMate to compile my documents, which compiles everything perfectly. But if I use some code which needs of `gnuplot` it isn't able to call it. See at the bottom for some examples.

On the contrary, if I call the file from the terminal with `pdflatex --shell-escape file.tex` then it compiles perfect.

### Question

What happens? Is it a PATH problem? How can I solve it? (I don't really understand what is a PATH, therefore I can't try/imagine by myself)

### Code and Logs

#### Example 1:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{gnuplottex}
\begin{document}
    \begin{gnuplot}
        plot sin(x)
    \end{gnuplot}
\end{document}
```

Part of the .log file

> ```
> \openout3 = `Ejercicio1-gnuplottex-fig1.gnuplot'.
>
> Opening gnuplot stream Ejercicio1-gnuplottex-fig1.gnuplot
> runsystem(gnuplot Ejercicio1-gnuplottex-fig1.gnuplot)...executed.
>
> Package gnuplottex Warning: Conversion of Ejercicio1-gnuplottex-fig1.gnuplot fa
> iled.
>
> Package gnuplottex Warning: Please convert Ejercicio1-gnuplottex-fig1.gnuplot m
> anually.
> ```

And from the terminal no error at all.

#### Example 2:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot gnuplot {sin(x)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The .log problems from TextMate:

> Latex Error: ./Ejercicio1.tex:6 Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, the
>   gnuplot-result file 'Ejercicio1.pgf-plot.table' could not be found.
>   Maybe you need to enable the shell-escape feature? For pdflatex, this
>   is '>> pdflatex -shell-escape'. You can also invoke '>> gnuplot
>   .gnuplot' manually on the respective gnuplot file..
>
> ! Package pgfplots Warning: You have an axis with empty range.
>   Replacing it with a default range and clearing all plots.

And no errors from terminal with `pdflatex --shell-escape file.tex`.

Comment: It may be that an upgraded installation of TextMate caused the `-shell-escape` option to be turned off. Recheck this option under Preferences in your LaTeX bundle. See [How and Why to use TextMate for LaTeX](http://www.astrobetter.com/how-and-why-to-use-textmate-for-latex/) (starting from **Setup**). Since I don't have TextMate nor a Mac, I'm unable to test this myself.

Comment: @Werner Well, thanks for the answer. That manual is for TM 1.5 (which I used before), but I don't know how to make it work in TM 2.0. And, of course, I'm not sure the problem is TextMate or gnuplot or whatever! Anyway, thank you for the answer.

Comment: So there's nothing in TM 2.0 under Preferences that you can change to include an option that is passed to `pdflatex`?

Comment: @Werner Yes, in TM 1.5 and TM 2.0 is the same: Bundles › LaTeX › Preferences…. But it seems that it's unresponsive in TM 2.0 with Mac OS X 10.8.2 (I'm asking because I updated so many things and I don't know which is the reason).

Comment: Can you successfully execute `pdflatex --shell-escape` on the command line?

Comment: And does it work on your LaTeX document with the gnuplot in it, i.e. `pdflatex --shell-escape YourDocument.tex` (should, \write18 is there)? And you have no trouble compiling simple LaTeX documents from TM 2.0?

Comment: @PercivalUlysses NO!. Edited my question again.

Comment: It sounds like the upgrade has messed with the way MacTeX adds itself to the path for finding programs. You might want to look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65143 and see if that helps: it should at the very least mean that at the Terminal you get the correct version of TeX being used.

Comment: Well, by some reason I needed to delete my old account and then create a new one (where I'm at this moment) and now no port (from MacPorts) work. Included gnuplot.

Comment: I agree with Joseph: Something with your PATH or the TeX configuration is wrong. I would suggest that you check if you have different versions of TeX installed (macports installs its binaries to */opt/bin*, MacTeX in */usr/texbin*, which is a soft link). If you are sure you're dealing with only one TeX installation, you can take a look at it with `texconfig conf`.

Comment: Well, I have a link in `/opt/local/bin` named `pdflatex` which links to `/opt/local/libexec/texlive/binaries/pdftex`. So I have two TeX installed. How can I delete the MacPorts one? How could I get my PATH right?

Comment: So you also have a directory `/usr/texbin`? What is the output of `which texconfig`?

Comment: Yes I have, and the output of that is `/usr/texbin/texconfig`.

Comment: OK. This is a bit strange, since it would indicate that on the shell, MacTeX comes before MacPorts TeXlive. Yet the output of your edits suggests that it is the other way round. What is the output of `which pdflatex`?

Comment: @PercivalUlysses `/usr/texbin/pdflatex`

Comment: Anyway, you have to locate `pgfplots.sty`. In which texmf tree is it?

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by *texmf tree*, but the `pgfplots.sty` (at least the one I think pdflatex usually uses) is in `/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgfplots`

Comment: If you are sure *pgfplots* is there, what happens when you `/usr/texbin/pdflatex mydocument.tex`, and what happens when you run `/opt/local/bin/pdflatex mydocument.tex`?

Comment: @PercivalUlysses `/usr/texbin/pdflatex mydocument.tex` works. The `/opt/…` doesn't. But now if I write `gnuplot` in the terminal it doesn't work, I need to write `/opt/bin/gnuplot`.

Comment: You have to put `/opt/local/bin` (and `/opt/local/sbin`) in your PATH. See [here](http://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them/284351#284351) for further explanation.

Comment: @PercivalUlysses Thank you. Now `gnuplot` works. And if I call `/usr/texbin/pdflatex --shell-escape doc.tex` it WORKS!! The only thing I need to do is make sure that `pdflatex` in terminal call `/usr/texbin/pdflatex` and not `/opt/local/bin/pdflatex` which is wrong.

Comment: OK. To ensure that `/usr/texbin/pdflatex` is called, `/usr/texbin` must be *before* `/opt/local/bin` in your PATH. See `echo $PATH` on your shell if it does. It would be interesting to know why your macports installed TeXlive. I guess there exists a dependency. You can check this with `port` and some options (see on their page). Maybe you can remove it. To something different: What's the matter with TextMate? Does it work now?

Comment: @PercivalUlysses Please, if this is not the method, tell me which is, but to put it before in my PATH I just edited the `/private/etc/paths` file and wrote `/usr/texbin` in the first line (and now it works well from the command line). But, still doesn't work from TM 2.0 (I will add some info tomorrow).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be an issue with TextMate's `PATH`, which is *not* (necessarily) the same as the `PATH` when you work from Terminal. You can check that TextMate is able to find gnuplot by opening a new file in TextMate, typing the line `which gnuplot`, and running that line with Ctrl-R. If TextMate gives you an error message, then it can't find gnuplot; if it prints a directory name then it can.

So assuming that TextMate can't find gnuplot, the easiest way to fix this is to go to TextMate's Preferences > Variables and edit the entry for PATH. You should change this so that the directory containing gnuplot is in the list, for example

```
/usr/texbin:$PATH:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/bin
```

might work for you. (It's important that you keep `$PATH` in this list too, otherwise TextMate won't be able to use many important commands.) Make sure the check box next to PATH is checked. Now if you open a new file and type `which gnuplot`, Ctrl-R, it should give you something, and if you type `which pdflatex`, Ctrl-R, it should say `/usr/texbin`.

Finally, you need to make sure that TextMate runs pdflatex with the `shell-escape` option. TextMate allows you to pass options to the TeX compiler using comments at the beginning of your document. Try adding this

```
%!TEX TS-options = --shell-escape
```

as the first line of your file. Both of the examples you provided compile without any problems on my machine if I include this as the first line. (TextMate 2.0-alpha.9387)

Comment: This is crazy. Now it works `pgfplots`'s commands which include calling gnuplot, but now `gnuplottex`'s commands doesn't work at all (neither from terminal nor TextMate). By the way, could you explain me what do you mean by *typing the line `which gnuplot` and running that line*? If I write a document with only that line, TextMate tells me `Latex Error: ./file.tex:1 LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

! Emergency stop.

! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!`. I will try again all possible cases and then comment.

Comment: @Manuel you want to use the "Execute Line" action in the Shell Script bundle, not the "Typeset & View" command from the LaTeX bundle. Ctrl-R, not Cmd-R. This is like telling TextMate to run a line in a terminal that TextMate launches for itself.

Comment: Done, of course it recognizes `gnuplot`: `/opt/local/bin/gnuplot`. And that folder is in my TextMate PATH. I have edited my question to explain what happens now. Read there. By the way, what does checking the PATH's checkbox do?

Comment: @Manuel, [`PATH`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) is an [environment variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) that lists locations to look for programs. When you check the checkbox in TM, it tells TM to use a different setting for this variable than the default. `gnuplot` is installed in a directory that is not in the default list of directories, so TM (and any program that TM runs) can't find `gnuplot` unless you change the value of `PATH` yourself. The `PATH` that TM sees is *not* the same `PATH` that you see when you run commands in Terminal.

Comment: I don't know, closed all, reopened all, and now it just works. The only thing I had to do was checking the PATH's checkbox. Thank you.