# Why can't TeXShop find pdflatex?

Tags: compiling, texshop

I have a MacOSX 10.7. I wanted to install MacTeX (2012) on my Mac. But after installing TeXShop could not compile a simple Text. I used a former version of MacTeX on my Tiger Systems for which it was working well. 
Now with the OSX10.7 I have the problem. I get the following error message:

```
/usr/texbin/pdflatex was not found. Perhaps TeXLive was not installed correct or get
 lost. In that case visit TeXShop website and follow the instructions to reinstall 
TeXLive. It also could be that the direction in TeXShop preferences is wrong. This 
could be when using the fink-distribution von teTeX.
```

I am looking forward for help.

[Edited Dec12 2013]: I am getting the same error on a new install of TexShop with BasicTex 2012. Deleting the preference file did not work!?!?

Comment: Try quitting out of TeXShop and deleting your TeXShop preferences.  It's `~/Library/Preferences/TeXShop.plist`  You can get to the `~/Library` folder using the Go menu in the Finder.

Comment: @anni Did you update your operating system? If so, you may need to fix described in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64973/how-do-i-restore-my-tex-path/65143#65143

Comment: The closing of this question was so nasty!

Comment: "This question is unlikely to help any future visitors." Given the ubiquity of LaTeX, the (general) robustness of its Mac implementation, not to speak of my search on this exact question as well as that of @WłodzimierzHolsztyński, this statement is ridiculous.

Comment: Mac has introduced a so-called protection against installing all kind of programs, especially useful programs. This stopped me from using TeX for a couple of years! Very recently I have learned (for a moment, I may relearn it) how to stop this so-called protection. Since then my TeXShop works (not 100% fully; possibly I should do some extra steps). If there is still an interest in this problem I can find what has helped me, let me know. BTW, it was nasty to close this question.

Comment: Just to show that closing this question was a mistake, I needed this information, nearly four years after the original question!

Comment: I needed the answer to this "localized" question today, as well. And I am sure that there are a lot more people who don't bother signing up just to says so.

Comment: I needed the answer to this question just now, too.  I already have an account so it was easy to comment.

Comment: i need the answer to this question *now* in order to answer a question from an author, "... pdflatex does not appear to be available in TexShop which is what I use ..."  i hope i can find help somewhere ...