# Configuring paths to TeX Live for TeXShop

Tags: texlive, mac, paths, texshop

I recently installed TeXShop, and proceeded to write some code and tried to preview it.  Unfortunately, I got an error message:

```
   Can't find required tool.
    /usr/texbin/simpdftex does not exist.
Perhaps TeXLive as not installed or was removed during a system upgrade.
If so, go to the TeXShop website and follow the instructions to (re)install TexLive.
Another possibility is that a tool path is incorrectly configured in TeXShop preferences.
This can happen if you are using the fink teTeX distribution.
```

I proceeded to install the complete version of TeX Live.  After restarting TeXShop, I find that I get the exact same error above.  I checked my `/usr/texbin` directory and found no such directory!  Furthermore, I looked at my preferences  and noticed under my path settings were set as follows:

```
(pdf)TeX: /usr/texbin
Distiller (ghostscript): /usr/local/bin
```

Should I change either of these paths?  Should I reinstall TeXShop?
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you install using the MacTeX version of TeX Live? That's what TeXShop assumes.  I would recommend that you do that.  If you did that and you're still having problems, try  quitting out of TeXShop and deleting your TeXShop preferences. It's `~/Library/Preferences/TeXShop.plist` You can get to the `~/Library` folder using the Go menu in the Finder. Alternatively, perhaps the following will help: [How do I restore my TeX path](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64973/2693).

Comment: @AlanMunn: How do I obtain the MacTeX version of TeXLive?

Comment: http://tug.org/mactex/ Most Mac users here will assume you have that installed, since it is bullet proof, and with very few exceptions, we all use it.

Comment: @AlanMunn: Thanks!  I just installed MacTeX and everything works perfectly now.

Comment: good to hear.  We'll close this question as "too localized" so that it doesn't hang around unanswered.

Comment: @AlanMunn:  That's fine with me! :)