# Create a local texmf tree in MacTeX

Tags: mactex, texmf

I know that TeX Users Group recommends putting your local texmf tree at `~/Library/texmf` (see [link](http://www.tug.org/mactex/2013/faq/index.html)). However, I want MacTeX to see my local texmf tree in a folder in my Dropbox. This allows me to refer to the same local texmf tree on multiple computers, which makes updating my local texmf tree easier (just update the version in the Dropbox and all the computers see the update).

How do I do this?

Note: I found some similar tex.stackexchange questions, but they don't answer my question.

- TeXLive on Mac [How to make LaTeX see local texmf tree](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30494/how-to-make-latex-see-local-texmf-tree)
- MikTeX on Windows [Create a local texmf tree in MiKTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-miktex?rq=1)

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on why http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30494/how-to-make-latex-see-local-texmf-tree doesn't cover this: you just need to add the appropriate location.

Comment: @JosephWright The answers in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30494/how-to-make-latex-see-local-texmf-tree use TeXLive commands, which don't exist in MacTeX. For example, when I try to run `tlmgr` or `kpsewhich` in the Terminal, bash tells me `command not found`

Comment: MacTeX is TeX Live plus a few extras: if you don't get `tlmgr` at the Terminal then something is (badly) up with your MacTeX installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I arrived at the solution.

First, I tried to run `tlmgr` but I got an error:

```
my-iMac:~ myname$ tlmgr
-bash: tlmgr: command not found
```

Based on Joseph Wright's comment, I realized that `tlmgr` must be installed. The question then was: where is it located in the file system?

Based on [tlmgr is not accessible after installing TeX Live 2011 on a Ubuntu system](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26624/tlmgr-is-not-accessible-after-installing-tex-live-2011-on-a-ubuntu-system), I found that on my system, `tlmgr` is located at

```
/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-darwin/tlmgr
```

Therefore, to add the folder `~/Dropbox/computer/localtexmf` to the LaTeX search path, I ran the command:

```
sudo /usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-darwin/tlmgr conf texmf TEXMFHOME "~/Library/texmf:~/Dropbox/computer/localtexmf"
```

Comment: Although this worked, it's not a long-term solution, since there is something wrong with how your path is set up in the command line. On a properly set up MacTeX system, `which tlmgr` should return `/usr/texbin/tlmgr`. Do you possibly have a MacPorts version of TeX installed as well?  What does `echo $PATH` return?

Comment: @AlanMunn I installed MacTeX by downloading `MacTeX.pkg` from [tug](http://tug.org/mactex/). Should I instead have used MacPorts or Homebrew? `echo $PATH` returns `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin`. According to [tug FAQ](http://www.tug.org/mactex/2013/faq/index.html), the PATH should be set up manually by modifying the shell startup script.

Comment: No, you shouldn't have installed via MacPorts or Homebrew.  But it's very odd that your path isn't set correctly.  See my answer to [Where is PATH modified to include /usr/texbin?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29746) for the correct way to fix your path system-wide. You may need to logout and back in for it to take effect.  (Or perhaps just close and reopen the Termina.)

Comment: @AlanMunn As per your answer, MacTeX does install a file `/etc/paths.d/TeX` with the contents `/usr/texbin`. But does Terminal incorporate the contents of this file into the PATH variable in general, or only for LaTeX programs?

Comment: Yes, it's system wide; that's what `/etc/paths.d` is for.

Comment: @AlanMunn Well, the existence of `/etc/paths.d/TeX` doesn't seem to automatically put `/usr/texbin` into my `PATH` based on the output of `echo $PATH`, even after I restarted the computer. Oh well!

Comment: Perhaps you are overwriting the path completely in a `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`? If you make a brand new account, does the path show up correctly?

Comment: @AlanMunn Indeed, there is a `.bash_profile` file that has the contents `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin`. When I delete the `.bash_profile` file, and restart Terminal, now `/usr/texbin` is on the path and the Terminal can find the `tlmgr` command. Thanks!