# ‘Article.cls’ not found after installing homebrew

Tags: kile

I’m using Kile as my primary editor on Max OS X and everything was working fine until yesterday. I installed homebrew and used it to install some other software.

I’m thinking some of my directories got moved around. How can I specify the search path for Kile? And how do I determine what the correct path is now?

I know I just have to set the TEXINPUTS environment variable, but can’t find where it should point to.

Comment: You do not need to set anything for kile, but you do need to set the PATH for mactex/texlive so that commands like pdflatex can be found on your system. Maybe this helps:http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29744/where-is-path-modified-to-include-usr-texbin

Comment: Check for reading permissions on `/usr/local/texlive/2013` and below it.

Comment: @egreg can you elaborate? I have `usr/local/texlive/2012` but I’m not sure where to navigate to after that.