# Where is tlmgr in MacPorts-TeXLive installation?

Tags: texlive, installing, mac, macports

I have just installed TeXLive-2014 through MacPorts. But it doesn't come with a `tlmgr` executable. I previously used TeXLive-2013 installed with MaxTeX.pkg which had `tlmgr` as part of its installation. I don't see why the MacPorts installation doesn't contain it.

I really need `tlmgr` to install, update and upgrade packages from CTAN with ease. If this is not possible, is there any substitute for `tlmgr` in the MacPorts installation of TeXLive?

Comment: No, it's nowhere.  See [Adding a CTAN package to a MacPorts-maintained TeX installation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50470) for some discussion why.  So the best solution is to install MacTeX and not to use MacPorts for TeX at all.

Comment: Sadly, my command line GNU Emacs editor only listens to the MacPorts installation. Strangely, the App version uses the MacTeX distro. Does anyone know a way to change the terminal Emacs path to use the MacTeX distro? Or should I post this as a separate question altogether?

Comment: Just add `/usr/texbin` to your PATH and Emacs should find the MacTeX version with no problems.

Comment: To do this properly see [Where is PATH modified to include /usr/texbin?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29744).  You will need to make sure that `/usr/texbin` comes before `opt/` in the PATH, though if you keep the MacPorts TeX.

Comment: I must say thanks. Your suggestion did not answer my question, however, it did solve my problem. I had set up my `.profile` to yield preference to MacPorts packages. I just had to include `export PATH=/user/texbin/:$PATH`. After sourcing, Emacs did use the MacTeX TeXLive 2013 installed earlier.