# How to migrate from TeXLive-MacPorts-2014 to TeXLive-MacTeX-2014

Tags: texlive, installing, mac, macports

I have installed TeXLive-MacPorts-2014 and would like to migrate to MacTeX-TeXLive-2014 (since MacPorts distro doesn't come with the tlmgr). I have installed some major sections of [MacPorts-TeXLivePackages](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/TeXLivePackages) including texlive-publishers and texlive-science.

After installing from MacTeX.pkg, how to install those sections described above in bulk. For instance, to install such sections in MacPorts, I had to run

`sudo port install texlive-<section>`

Can you do the same with `tlmgr` or TeXLive Utility app? Or is there any other similar simple solution for this matter?

If so, when migrated, I would like the MacPorts-TeXLive executables and the MacTeX-TeXLive executables to share the same package space. Is this possible?

Edit:
I suppose creating aliases that MacPorts use may be a plausible solution. If so, what are the aliases or symbolic links that should be created and where?

Comment: Related to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244465/where-is-tlmgr-in-macports-texlive-installation and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244467/how-to-configure-texstudio-to-use-macports-installation-of-texlive

Comment: Unless you are in a rush, you might want to hang on and install MacTeX 2015 when it is published. The MacTeX download is enormous. If you can, I'd waith until 2015 comes out and then migrate from MacPorts at the same time. Not sure why you would want both installed but you may need to install a 'dummy' package to keep MacPorts happy if you want to install an editor or something from there.

Comment: What might be the major improvements in MacTeX 2015 which is not present in the 2014 version? What makes it worthwhile to wait?

Comment: Does anyone happen to know the release date of MacTeX 2015?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install TeXLive via the MacTeX distribution, you essentially get everything, and you should not have to install anything separately.  This is different from the way MacPorts works, since it uses the TeXLive distribution divisions.  The MacTeX maintainers chose not to distribute MacTeX in this way, which in the long run makes life simpler: you have a single (albeit large) download, and then everything just works out of the box.

So if you install MacTeX there is no real need to keep the MacPorts distribution around, nor to transfer any of it.

As for using the MacPorts executables and sharing the distribution, this could probably be done by creating symbolic links, but I have no details to add, not having MacPorts installed.

Comment: I am in a need to keep MacPort-2014 distribution happy. It seems to be the dependancy for many of the `.el` packages I install through MacPorts.

Comment: Great. I've made up my mind to use MacTex.  Now, how do I uninstall MacPorts-TeXLive? port uninstall tex-live is not working.

Comment: I don't have MacPorts installed, but the following question might be of some use: [How can I uninstall the macports tex packages?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/95783)