# On Zsh Mac : Cannot find tlmgr even though it's installed

Tags: tlmgr

After switching to zsh from bash, I can't use the tlmgr command anymore (`zsh: command not found: tlmgr`).

My tex lives in

```
kpsewhich latex.ltx 
/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx
```

My tlmgr is in `/opt/local/share/tlpkg/TeXLive`

I tried to set PATH to either of the two, but can't manage to change it so that I can use the `tlmgr` command. Please help. Thanks! T

Comment: You need a path to a  `bin` directory that contains for example `pdftex`, see e.g. http://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html

Comment: How did you install TeX Live?

Comment: neither of those look like a bin directory, you say you can not find tlmgr but that is usually same place as latex, can you use latex? what does `which latex` report?

Comment: What OS version are you using? In recent versions of the OS you can’t install in /. Previous questions need to be answered too.

Comment: Thanks all - I figured out the problem was that I installed with Macports and there was no tlmgr included - see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244465/where-is-tlmgr-in-macports-texlive-installation?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem was that I installed TeX via mac ports and there was no tlmgr included. So I needed to do [Adding a CTAN package to a MacPorts-maintained TeX installation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50470/adding-a-ctan-package-to-a-macports-maintained-tex-installation)

Comment: Avoid MacPorts. If you still want to use it, by no means install TeX Live through it. Use the official MacTeX distribution.

Comment: I must say thanks! You saved me a lot of time. I de-installed the texlive-basic port I had and went with MacTeX :)