# TeXShop not working with Yosemite 10.10.4

Tags: mactex, texshop

I downloaded MacTex.pkg, installed texshop, but I get the following error:

/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex does not exist. TeXShop is  a front end for TeX, but you also need a TeX distribution. Perhaps such a distribution was not installed or was removed during a system upgrade. If so, go to http://tug.org/MacTeX and follow the instructions to (re)install MacTeX. A less likely possibility is that a tool path is incorrectly configured in TeXShop preferences. This can happen if you are using the macports or fink distributions.

PLEASE help. I am very new to both Mac and LaTeX so if someone could "hold my hand" so to speak, that would be really great.

Comment: did you install MacTex or just download it? Silly question perhaps. Open up a terminal and type `tex --version` in it. What happens?

Comment: @MHH I installed it. and when I type tex -- version I get tex: command not found.

Comment: you might find some help in the answer to this question: [How do I debug a failed MacTex installation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/257607/579)

Comment: Thank you @barbarabeeton but looks like my installation was fine. I uninstalled everything and re-installed again, yet the error persists.

Comment: I found a solution. In the engine, if you replace the Tex path from the default /Library/Programs/texbin to  /Library/TeX/Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Programs/texbin

Comment: The path in TeXShop should be `/Library/TeX/texbin` for MacTeX 2015, and `/usr/texbin` for MacTeX 2014 and earlier. If `tex --version` is not found, your `PATH` environment variable in the Terminal is incorrect. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29744/where-is-path-modified-to-include-usr-texbin may help with that.